# jQuery is visible doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm try to make an input non-editable after user click on icon and will chose date by select. So, i tought if i did a jQuery script for check if that date salect is visible than make a date text input non-editable.
But it doesn't work, i tried it woth .css and .is(":visible") but no one worked.

My code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($('#dropdown-date').is(':visible')) {
            document.getElementById('datumNaroz').disabled = true;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('datumNaroz').disabled = false;
        }
if ($('#dropdown-date').css('display') == 'none') {
            document.getElementById('datumNaroz').disabled = false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('datumNaroz').disabled = true;
        }
$('#dropdown-date').click(function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        });        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="datumNaroz">Birth date</label>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="input-group datum-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="datumNaroz" type="text" placeholder="Day / Month / Year" name="datumNaroz" maxlength="14" autocomplete="off" required>
          <div class="input-group-append" id="pickerToggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="custom-date dropright">
            <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-date">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <select class="custom-select" id="den">
                    <option value="day" disabled selected hidden>Day</option> 
                    <option value="02">02</option>    
                  </select>
                  <select class="custom-select" id="den">
                    <option value="month" disabled selected hidden>Month</option>
                    <option value="09">September</option> 
                  </select>
                  <select class="custom-select" id="den">
                    <option value="year" disabled selected hidden>Year</option>
                    <option value="1995">1995</option> 
                  </select>               
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.is` takes a selector.

Comment: selector should be `:visible`. you are just missing the `:`

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, not your PHP

Comment: I changed to .is(":visible"), but still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: Nope. And if I add console.log($('#dropdown-date').is(':visible')); so it remains false.